# How to remove trailing 0's from C++ Vector

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to remove trailing zero's from a C++ vector using a while loop with pop_back. If the last element of the vector is 0, it should pop back the last element, until it is not 0 anymore.

It's hard to understand what the errors mean, I would really appreciate it if someone more wise can help decipher these errors for me please!

```
void Integer::unzero() {

  while ((*this).bits_vector[((*this).bits_vector.size)] == 0) {
    (*this).bits_vector.pop_back;
  }
}
```

errors:

```
error C2679: binary '[': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'overloaded-function' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

error C3867: 'std::vector<bool,std::allocator<_Ty>>::pop_back': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member
```

Comment: On an unrelated note: `(*this).bits_vector` is the same as `this->bits_vector`, and in the scope of the class it's also the same as just `bits_vector`.

Comment: You need to use `()` for `size()` and `pop_back()`

Comment: On a more serious note, but unrelated to the error you have, when you fix the problem you will be indexing the vector *out of bounds* which is *undefined behavior*. Vector indexes are, just like array indexes, based on zero. That means indexes in a vector goes from zero to `size() - 1`.

Comment: Thanks so much! Definitely learned a lot

Comment: Wow, all those parentheses give me a headache! `while (this->bits_vector[this->bits_vector.size()] == 0) ...`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the expression `(*this).bits_vector.size` you use [the `size` member *function*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size) as a value, you don't call the function.

Same problem with [`pop_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/pop_back), it's a member *function* that you need to *call*.

So your fixed code (considering my comments as well) should look like

```
while (!bits_vector.empty() && bits_vector[bits_vector.size() - 1] == 0) {
    bits_vector.pop_back();
}
```

<sub>Note that I added a check to make sure the vector isn't empty, because if it is you would otherwise have a negative index.</sub>

Comment: @Alexander You can get rid of loop indices and write: `while ( !v.empty() && v.back() == 0 ) { v.pop_back(); }`

Answer (score 5):

Using [std::find_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) and [std::vector::erase](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase):

```
auto rit = std::find_if(bits_vector.rbegin(), bits_vector.rend(), 
                        [](int v) { return v != 0; });
bits_vector.erase(rit.base(), end(bits_vector));
```

Btw you forgot the parenthesis: `bits_vector.size()` and `bits_vector.pop_back()`.

Answer (score 2):

This will remove the trailing zeros by modifying the vector once.

```
int i;
for(i = v.size() - 1; i >= 0 && v[i] == 0; --i);
bits_vector.resize(i + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(*this).bits_vector.pop_back;
```

does not call the function. It just evaluates to a member function. Use:

```
(*this).bits_vector.pop_back();
```

You have the same problem with the `size` member function.

```
while ((*this).bits_vector[((*this).bits_vector.size)] == 0) {
                                            ^^^^^^
```

You don't need to use `size()` and the `[]` operator. You can simply use:

```
while ( !(*this).bits_vector.empty() &&   // Makes sure you don't call back() on an empty vector
       (*this).bits_vector.back() == 0) {
  (*this).bits_vector.pop_back();
}
```

Comment: note that it's safer to also check for !empty() before accessing back()